# How do I transcode the audio to aac in this ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I usually use this command to convert my mkv to mp4 while hardcoding the subtitles (for playing on my tv)

```
ffmpeg -i old_video.mkv -vf subtitles=old_video.mkv -acodec copy new_video.mp4
```

There is one mkv that produces an error, and I assume it is because the audio is FLAC not AAC so won't fit into mp4. How do I change the command ?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i old_video.mkv -vf subtitles=old_video.mkv -acodec aac new_video.mp4
```

You will need to add `-strict -2` or `-strict experimental` if you are using an older ffmpeg.